# Trying to make tool on device using theos and iPhone6

Tags: theos

I have read the [Theos/Setup](http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/Theos/Setup) on the iPhoneDev Wiki.

I have installed Theos into /var/theos (private/var/theos) and have copied in the iPhone8.1.sdk into /var/theos/sdks/iPhone8.1.sdk:

```
iPhone:/var/theos/sdks root# ls -al
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 3 root admin 102 Nov  7 08:11 ./
drwxr-xr-x 9 root admin 374 Nov  7 07:58 ../
drwxrwxr-x 5 root admin 306 Nov  7 08:01 iPhoneOS8.1.sdk/
```

I have fixed the issues with perl/rsync not being compiled for arm64 by following [the instructions](http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/Theos/Setup#Architecture_.28partial.29_incompatibility)

I created a tool:

```
$THEOS/bin/nic.pl
....
iPhone:~/Work/test root# ls
Makefile  control  main.mm  theos@
```

However, when I make, I get the following error:

```
iPhone:~/Work/test root# make
/var/theos/makefiles/common.mk:116: *** The "iphone" target is not supported on the "iphone" platform.  Stop.
```

What am I doing wrong? Or is this a problem with the 8.1 sdk?

Comment: Share your Makefile please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the article at http://sharedroutine.com/?p=11 got it working for me.

I symlinked /var/theos/makefiles/platform/Darwin-arm to /var/theos/makefiles/platform/Darwin-arm64 and forgot to symlink /var/theos/makefiles/targets/Darwin-arm to /var/theos/makefiles/targets/Darwin-arm64.

`ln -s /var/theos/makefiles/targets/Darwin-arm /var/theos/makefiles/targets/Darwin-arm64
ln -s /var/theos/makefiles/platform/Darwin-arm /var/theos/makefiles/platform/Darwin-arm64`

Your paths may be different.